# Laravel 5.1 wrong instance of Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, namespaces, laravel-5.1

I have a class that I am trying to swap out the facade usage of Crypt::encrypt with dependency injection:

```
       <?php namespace App\Libraries;

        use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;

        class MyClass
        {

            public function __construct(Encrypter $encrypter)
            {
                $this->encrypter= $encrypter;
            }

            public function myMethod()
            {
                $this->encrypter->crypt('somevalue');
            }

         }
```

The wrong instance is getting instantiated:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Libraries\MyClass::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter, instance of
>   Illuminate\Encryption\McryptEncrypter given

The facade resolves without an issue but I'd like to understand why DI is failing.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
Crypt::encrypt('somevalue');
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It because you had registered `McryptEncrypter` instead of `Encrypter`.
It could be if you have unsupported cipher or key.
For more information look in `Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider`.

```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter;

    class MyClass
    {

        public function __construct(Encrypter $encrypter)
        {
            $this->encrypter= $encrypter;
        }

        public function myMethod()
        {
            $this->encrypter->crypt('somevalue');
        }

     }
```

Also, follow SOLI**D** principles `Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.` Replace Encrypter concrete realisation to it interface.

> The facade resolves without an issue but I'd like to understand why DI is failing.

Facade works because he just resolves what you register, in your case it `McryptEncrypter`

Hope it will help.

Comment: The proper function is `encrypt`.

Comment: I think your cipher either needs to be 'AES-128-CBC' or 'AES-256-CBC'

Comment: Encrypter hasn't `crypt` method, but has `encrypt`

Comment: Like already mention there is no method called `crypt` as you can see here: `interface Encrypter
{
    /**
     * Encrypt the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function encrypt($value);

    /**
     * Decrypt the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $payload
     * @return string
     */
    public function decrypt($payload);
}` There is only `encrypt` and `decrypt`, This answer is the right way to do it, by using contracts

Answer (score 0):

The FQCN of the Laravel `Encrypter` ***interface*** (highlight by me) is:

- `Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter`

The method you defined:

```
        public function __construct(Encrypter $encrypter)
        {
            $this->encrypter= $encrypter;
        }
```

does not make use of that interface. Unless you don't make use of the correct interface, PHP will rightfully and totally correct present you the error message and luckily prevents your program from running:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Libraries\MyClass::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter, instance of Illuminate\Encryption\McryptEncrypter given

You have breached the contract!

Use the correct interface for the argument so that DI works as intended.